# One type (function pointer) is more general than the other

Tags: rust

I reached this error in this example, and I'm trying to understand what's happening.

```
use futures::future::{BoxFuture, FutureExt};
use std::sync::Arc;
use futures::lock::Mutex;

struct Message {}
struct Client {}

enum Error {
    ConnectionClosed,
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct MyType{}

impl Client {
    fn send_and_expect<'a, R: 'a + Default + Send>(
        client: Arc<Mutex<Self>>,
        message: &'a Message,
    ) -> BoxFuture<'a, Result<R, Error>> {
        async move { Ok(R::default()) }.boxed()
    }

    pub fn connection_retrier<'a, R: 'a + Default + Send>(
        client: Arc<Mutex<Self>>,
        f: for<'b> fn(Arc<Mutex<Self>>, &'b Message) -> BoxFuture<'b, Result<R, Error>>,
        f_m: &'a Message,
    ) -> BoxFuture<'a, Result<R, Error>>
    {
        async move {Ok(R::default())}.boxed()
    }

    async fn send_with_retry<'a>(
        client: Arc<Mutex<Self>>,
        message: &'a Message,
    ) -> Result<MyType, Error> {
        let client = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Client{}));
        Self::connection_retrier::<MyType>(client, Self::send_and_expect, message)
            .await
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:36:52
   |
36 |         Self::connection_retrier::<MyType>(client, Self::send_and_expect, message)
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'b> fn(Arc<_>, &'b Message) -> Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<MyType, Error>> + std::marker::Send + 'b)>>`
              found fn pointer `fn(Arc<_>, &Message) -> Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<MyType, Error>> + std::marker::Send>>`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7381e05a0e0111427053f3a3a5b9122d)

Well, `connection_retrier` requres a function `f: for<'b> fn(Arc<Mutex<Self>>, &'b Message) -> BoxFuture<'b, Result<R, Error>>,`. The one I passed seems to fit the signature.

The way I view `for<'b> fn...` is: I accept a function `f` for any lifetime `'b` presented. So, for the particular lifetime `'a`, `send_and_expect` seems to fit everything.

The only suspicion I have is for the lifetime of `R` being fixed at `'a` in `connection_retrier` so the `f` with its `for<'b>` is not free to give any lifetime for its `R`. I think the lifetime of the `R` in `f` should be `'b`. Is it possible to force `f` to have `R` with lifetime `'b`?

Something like this:

```
    f: for<'b> fn<RR: 'b>(Arc<Mutex<Self>>, &'b Message) -> BoxFuture<'b, Result<RR, Error>>,
```

Answer (score 3):

This error looks to be caused by limitation of the compiler's ability to automatically convert generic functions which include a type bounded by a lifetime into a function pointer that is fully generic over that lifetime. I'm not quite sure why this limitation exists, but it can be worked around by wrapping the generic call in a non-generic closure. All you need to do to make your example compile is to change:

```
Self::send_and_expect
```

to

```
|c, m| Self::send_and_expect(c, m)
```

Thus hiding the generic from the compiler.

Comment: I made the example a bit simpler than what I had here. I now get an error about the lifetime of `R` when applying your solution to my more complete example. Could you take a look? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b86fbf2dbd5d4e805e5aea9cf963a65b

Comment: @Gatonito The issue is that since `R` is bounded by the lifetime `'a`, `Self::send_and_expect<R>` can't count as `for<'b> fn(Arc<Mutex<Self>>, &'b Message) -> BoxFuture<'b, Result<R, Error>>`, since it's not valid for *every* lifetime `'b`, just those where `'a: 'b`. Sadly, this is another kind of bound we cannot express. However, the good news is you don't actually need the HRTB anymore, now that you've put the `Client` in an `Arc`. Simply this will work, even with recursion: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=49dbd7704f73f2454f6709c0cec9dadf

Comment: Nice. Very nice that you remembered the last question. What you think of putting Client in Arc? I had to because passing in `&mut Client` between `async` functions was hard or impossible when I actually filled that old example with real code inside the functions I defined

Comment: @Gatonito Strikes me as a perfectly reasonable solution. Sometimes the borrow checker just isn't smart enough to prove what you're doing is correct, or at least it would take too long to figure out a way to express it. If you're doing network I/O the overhead of `Arc` is probably insignificant in comparison anyway. The only concern is that now that you don't have the borrow checker on your back it's on you not to deadlock the `Mutex` (i.e. hold two mutable refs to the client).