# Rust HRTB is identical but compiler says one type is more general than the other

Tags: rust

The [following code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1ae07ce4d139158b82f84a970d2fe4d3) is fully type annotated:

```rust
fn enter<'a, F, R>(x: &'a i32, func: F) -> R
where
    F: for<'b> FnOnce(&'b i32) -> R,
{
    func(x)
}

fn identity<'a>(x: &'a i32) -> &'a i32 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let x = &42;
    enter(x, identity);
}
```

The compiler reports an error when compiling it:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     enter(x, identity);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected trait `for<'b> FnOnce<(&'b i32,)>`
              found trait `for<'a> FnOnce<(&'a i32,)>`
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/main.rs:3:35
   |
3  |     F: for<'b> FnOnce(&'b i32) -> R,
   |                                   ^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

My understanding is that the trait bound `for<'b> FnOnce(&'b i32) -> R` is more general than `identity`'s signature `for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> &'a i32`, so it should pass.

However, the generic `-> R` seems to be the culprit that stops the compilation but I don't know why.

I noticed there are similar questions, but they experienced the error because their types were not fully annotated and the compiler incorrectly inferred the type.

Related:

- [Rust "expected type" error prints mismatched types that are exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54341465/)
- [One type (function pointer) is more general than the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342223/)
- ["one type is more general than the other" error in Rust while types are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68707757/)
- [Creating an alias for a Fn trait results in "one type is more general than the other" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597152/)
- https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-one-type-is-more-general-than-the-other-but-they-are-exactly-the-same/25194

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that the trait bound `for<'b> FnOnce(&'b i32) -> R` is more general than `identity`'s signature `for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> &'a i32`, so it should pass.

No it is not. When `R` is declared, `'b` is not in the context, so it cannot depend on it (this is one way to view that, there are others).

This is *necessary* for APIs like [`std::thread::LocalKey::with()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/struct.LocalKey.html#method.with) to be sound: if `R` was allowed to contain the lifetime (implicit in the case of `with()`), references to the thread local could escape the closure and `with()`, and then used on different threads, causing UB.

As far as I know, there is no way to have a generic return type and allow it to reference the parameters.