# Debugging rust lifetimes: how to check which scope each elided lifetime is related to?

Tags: rust, lifetime, lifetime-scoping

Consider the following example:

```
struct Test<'l, T> {
    t: &'l T,
}

fn test<'lt, F, T>(f: F) -> T
where
    F: for<'t> FnOnce(&'t String) -> T,
{
    let str = String::from("test");
    return f(&str);
}

fn main(){
    test(|s| {
        println!("{}", s);
        Test { t: s } //error: lifetime may not live long enough
    });
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=394b9e0c6dc15dae109e81d7412b0ff8)

Here is the detailed error message `rust` compiler emits:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:16:9
   |
14 |     test(|s| {
   |           -- return type of closure is Test<'2, String>
   |           |
   |           has type `&'1 String`
15 |         println!("{}", s);
16 |         Test { t: s } //error: lifetime may not live long enough
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

From what I understand the lifetime `&'2` is related to `fn main()` function scope since the return value `Test { t: s }` transfers ownership to a caller from `main` and therefore should be valid within `main`.

I'm curious if there any other way to debug incorrect lifetimes than looking at it with eyes and trying to understand what went wrong? Maybe some verbose `rustc` output or similar?

I suspect in much more complicated cases such debugging might be time consuming so probably there's an automated way to track lifetimes out there?

Comment: The issue is that `str: String` lives within `test()`, but you're attempting to return a reference to `str` from `test()`. As soon as `test()` returns `str` no longer lives. This cannot be fixed with lifetimes, since `test` created `str`, so you need to return an owned value instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust HRTB is identical but compiler says one type is more general than the other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75440244/7884305)

Comment: Do you want an explanation why this code is not accepted (the answer I linked above), or general tips on how to debug lifetime errors? Because for the latter, I don't have answer besides experience, and I'm also afraid it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman In this relatively short example it's more-or-less clear how to identify the problem, but in case of large projects with complicated dependency chain it might be extremely time consuming process. That's why I was wondering if there's something out there to simplify borrowchecker errors debugging.

Comment: As I said, I don't know such tool (I recall seeing https://github.com/rustviz/rustviz which aims to visualize lifetimes, but I don't know how it fares with complex errors (haven't tried it) and I'm afraid it won't be useful in large projects. In general, the compiler errors try to be as useful as they can, but in more complex errors it doesn't always work (you are welcome to open an issue!) and then only practice will help (or you can ask here!) Usually, trying to minimize the code (which is also a requirement for asking here) can help you identify the problem.